# Setting Cells or Ranges to Blank on different worksheets through VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I am having difficulty setting Ranges and cells to a blank value on different worksheets, UNLESS the worksheet is visible.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub Clean_Up_Ranges()
    Dim nm As Worksheet
        On Error Resume Next
    For Each nm In Worksheets
            Worksheets("nm").Select
         Range("d7:d37") = ""
        Range("k7:k37") = ""

        Range("L40:l42") = ""
'..... plenty more ranges
        Range("h80:j179") = ""
        Calculate

        Debug.Print nm.Name

    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Your Worksheets ("nm").Select was incorrect because "nm" wasn't the actual name of the worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly reference the sheet.

```
Sub Clean_Up_Ranges()
    Dim nm As Worksheet
        On Error Resume Next
    For Each nm In Worksheets
            'Worksheets("nm").Select
         nm.Range("d7:d37") = ""
        nm.Range("k7:k37") = ""

        nm.Range("L40:l42") = ""
'..... plenty more ranges
        nm.Range("h80:j179") = ""
        Calculate

        Debug.Print nm.Name

    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Bingo, worked exactly as advertised. Thanks you very much SIR.  Very nice.

Comment: I would love to mark "as Answered"  How do I do that?

Comment: @AOldTunaGuy You should see a checkmark below the voting up and down arrows.  Just to the left of the top of this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Activate` keyword in your code which will activate the sheet.

[See This](http://www.analytics-tools.com/2009/10/vba-difference-between-sheetsselect-and.html) to know difference between SHEETS.SELECT or SHEETS.ACTIVATE.

```
Sub Clean_Up_Ranges()
    Dim nm As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each nm In Worksheets
         nm.Activate              'Activate the sheet

         Range("d7:d37") = ""
        Range("k7:k37") = ""

        Range("L40:l42") = ""
'..... plenty more ranges
        Range("h80:j179") = ""
        Calculate

        Debug.Print nm.Name

    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Worked as well.  Apprieciate your time.